# Spiral Matrix in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a matrix based on user input. I want to start this as given below

Input: 3

Output: create 3x3 matrix like below, start from 1 then 2 and add previous two numbers.

```
3   2    1
5   55   34  
8   13   21
```

if user gives input as 4 then it should create a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Yes it is possible in several different ways. What have you tried so far? Some code might be helpful for the people that want to help you solving your problem for example

Comment: The middle line must be `5 55 34`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static int[][] DIRS = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}};

static boolean canGo(int[][] a, int n, int r, int c) {
    if (r < 0 || r >= n)
        return false;
    if (c < 0 || c >= n)
        return false;
    if (a[r][c] > 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

static int[][] solve(int n) {
    int max = n * n;
    int[][] array = new int[n][n];
    int dir = 0, prev = 1, cur = 1;
    int row = 0, col = n - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; ++i) {
        array[row][col] = cur;
        if (!canGo(array, n, row + DIRS[dir][0], col + DIRS[dir][1]))
            dir = (dir + 1) % DIRS.length;
        row += DIRS[dir][0];
        col += DIRS[dir][1];
        int temp = cur;
        cur = prev + cur;
        prev = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

and

```
int[][] a = solve(3);
for (int[] row : a)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

result:

```
[3, 2, 1]
[5, 55, 34]
[8, 13, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very well possible in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If I write down the code and give it to you, it won't be along the spirit of SE. So let me direct you in what way you should think.

- Try to solve it in O(n) complexity.
- Perhaps start with a loop that runs from 1 to nxn
- For each iteration, get the sum by adding the previous two numbers.
- For each iteration, get the x and y index of the 2D array using i.
- Something like x = f1(i), and y = f2(i) [ This will be the tricky part ]
- assign a[x][y] = sum.

Again, this is not a solution, but a possible way you should think forward.